# Grouping Data by field in Django

Tags: python, django, models

as chapters grouped by season:

Season 1:
    Chapter 1
    Chapter 2
    Chapter 3
    Chapter 4

Season 2:
    Chapter 1
    Chapter 2
    Chapter 3

Example image https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvaqM.png

```
#models.py

class Serie(models.Model):
    # optional fields

    def serie_chapter(self):
        return self.seriechapter_set.order_by("season","chapter")

class SerieChapter(models.Model):
    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    season = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, choices=CHOICES_SEASON)
    chapter = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES_EPISODE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So, then as I can add chapters per season?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more class

```
class series_chapter(models.Model):
    series=models.ForeignKey(Serie)
    chapter=models.ForeignKey(SerieChapter)
```

In class SerieChapter you won't need

```
serie=models.Foreignkey(Serie)
```

for season 1 you want to add episode1 and episode2
then first add series and chapters in their respective models.
Then in series_chapter

```
s1c1=series_chapter.objects.create(series=instance_of_serie,chapter=instance_of_Seriechapter)#for chapter 1
s1c2=series_chapter.objects.create(series=instance_of_serie,chapter=instance_of_Seriechapter)#for chapter 2
```